# CSS: SVG sprite is not working

Tags: css, svg

I want to combine all SVG icons in one sprite, and call it from CSS like we do in other background-image cases.But it don't shown in the page. When opening SVG image in browser I get this error
http://gyazo.com/814ab252f2c104caf10fcef2d2f1d057

HTML

```
  <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 input-group">
       <span class="input-group-addon login-icon icon-banner">
             <i class="icons icon-username"></i>
        </span>           
    </div>
```

Css

```
.icons{
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background:url('../images/icons/icons.svg') no-repeat;
}
```

This is the SVG image http://gyazo.com/25f8140160e3cb27b850a9b2916492f3

SVG markup is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 17.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="126.099px" height="93.106px" viewBox="0 0 126.099 93.106" enable-background="new 0 0 126.099 93.106"
     xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Page-1" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Icons" transform="translate(-188.000000, -371.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
        <path id="Username" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#F16059" d="M254.34,387.458c-0.067-0.743-0.045-1.249-0.045-1.913
            c0.349-0.18,0.967-1.294,1.069-2.228c0.27-0.022,0.697-0.27,0.821-1.283c0.068-0.54-0.191-0.844-0.36-0.934
            c0.439-1.283,1.361-5.231-1.699-5.636c-0.315-0.529-1.125-0.799-2.171-0.799c-4.196,0.079-4.702,3.038-3.78,6.435
            c-0.169,0.09-0.428,0.394-0.36,0.934c0.124,1.013,0.551,1.26,0.821,1.283c0.101,0.934,0.743,2.048,1.091,2.228
            c0,0.664,0.034,1.17-0.045,1.913c-0.821,2.137-6.424,1.08-6.682,5.209h18C260.741,388.538,255.173,389.595,254.34,387.458"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Page-1_1_" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Icons_1_" transform="translate(-188.000000, -371.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
        <path id="Username_1_" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#C8C7C7" d="M203.34,387.458c-0.067-0.743-0.045-1.249-0.045-1.913
            c0.349-0.18,0.967-1.294,1.069-2.228c0.27-0.022,0.697-0.27,0.821-1.283c0.068-0.54-0.191-0.844-0.36-0.934
            c0.439-1.283,1.361-5.231-1.699-5.636c-0.315-0.529-1.125-0.799-2.171-0.799c-4.196,0.079-4.702,3.038-3.78,6.435
            c-0.169,0.09-0.428,0.394-0.36,0.934c0.124,1.013,0.551,1.26,0.821,1.283c0.101,0.934,0.743,2.048,1.091,2.228
            c0,0.664,0.034,1.17-0.045,1.913c-0.821,2.137-6.424,1.08-6.682,5.209h18C209.741,388.538,204.173,389.595,203.34,387.458"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Page-1_2_" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Icons_2_" transform="translate(-188.000000, -371.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
        <path id="Username_2_" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#37424E" d="M229.007,387.459c-0.067-0.743-0.045-1.249-0.045-1.913
            c0.349-0.18,0.967-1.294,1.069-2.228c0.27-0.022,0.697-0.27,0.821-1.283c0.068-0.54-0.191-0.844-0.36-0.934
            c0.439-1.283,1.361-5.231-1.699-5.636c-0.315-0.529-1.125-0.799-2.171-0.799c-4.196,0.079-4.702,3.038-3.78,6.435
            c-0.169,0.09-0.428,0.394-0.36,0.934c0.124,1.013,0.551,1.26,0.821,1.283c0.101,0.934,0.743,2.048,1.091,2.228
            c0,0.664,0.034,1.17-0.045,1.913c-0.821,2.137-6.424,1.08-6.682,5.209h18C235.408,388.539,229.84,389.597,229.007,387.459"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Page-1_3_" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Icons_3_" transform="translate(-190.000000, -408.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
        <path id="Password" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#C8C7C7" d="M208.975,444.215h-0.898v-2.197
            c0-2.769-2.277-5.021-5.077-5.021c-2.799,0-5.077,2.253-5.077,5.021v2.197h-0.898c-0.29,0-0.525,0.233-0.525,0.519v9.743
            c0,0.287,0.235,0.52,0.525,0.52h11.95c0.29,0,0.525-0.233,0.525-0.52v-9.743C209.5,444.447,209.265,444.215,208.975,444.215
            L208.975,444.215z M203.819,450.145v2.074c0,0.181-0.148,0.328-0.332,0.328h-0.974c-0.183,0-0.332-0.147-0.332-0.328v-2.074
            c-0.362-0.254-0.599-0.672-0.599-1.145c0-0.774,0.635-1.402,1.418-1.402c0.783,0,1.418,0.628,1.418,1.402
            C204.418,449.473,204.181,449.891,203.819,450.145L203.819,450.145z M205.653,444.215h-5.306v-2.197
            c0-1.447,1.19-2.624,2.653-2.624c1.463,0,2.653,1.177,2.653,2.624V444.215L205.653,444.215z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Page-1_4_" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Icons_4_" transform="translate(-190.000000, -408.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
        <path id="Password_1_" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#37424E" d="M234.642,444.215h-0.898v-2.197
            c0-2.769-2.277-5.021-5.077-5.021c-2.799,0-5.077,2.253-5.077,5.021v2.197h-0.898c-0.29,0-0.525,0.233-0.525,0.519v9.743
            c0,0.287,0.235,0.52,0.525,0.52h11.95c0.29,0,0.525-0.233,0.525-0.52v-9.743C235.167,444.448,234.932,444.215,234.642,444.215
            L234.642,444.215z M229.486,450.145v2.074c0,0.181-0.148,0.328-0.332,0.328h-0.974c-0.183,0-0.332-0.147-0.332-0.328v-2.074
            c-0.362-0.254-0.599-0.672-0.599-1.145c0-0.774,0.635-1.402,1.418-1.402s1.418,0.628,1.418,1.402
            C230.085,449.473,229.848,449.891,229.486,450.145L229.486,450.145z M231.32,444.215h-5.306v-2.197
            c0-1.447,1.19-2.624,2.653-2.624s2.653,1.177,2.653,2.624V444.215L231.32,444.215z"/>
    </g>
</g>
<g id="Page-1_5_" sketch:type="MSPage">
    <g id="Icons_5_" transform="translate(-190.000000, -408.000000)" sketch:type="MSArtboardGroup">
        <path id="Password_2_" sketch:type="MSShapeGroup" fill="#F16059" d="M259.975,444.215h-0.898v-2.197
            c0-2.769-2.277-5.021-5.077-5.021c-2.799,0-5.077,2.253-5.077,5.021v2.197h-0.898c-0.29,0-0.525,0.233-0.525,0.519v9.743
            c0,0.287,0.235,0.52,0.525,0.52h11.95c0.29,0,0.525-0.233,0.525-0.52v-9.743C260.5,444.448,260.265,444.215,259.975,444.215
            L259.975,444.215z M254.819,450.145v2.074c0,0.181-0.148,0.328-0.332,0.328h-0.974c-0.183,0-0.332-0.147-0.332-0.328v-2.074
            c-0.362-0.254-0.599-0.672-0.599-1.145c0-0.774,0.635-1.402,1.418-1.402c0.783,0,1.418,0.628,1.418,1.402
            C255.418,449.473,255.181,449.891,254.819,450.145L254.819,450.145z M256.653,444.215h-5.306v-2.197
            c0-1.447,1.19-2.624,2.653-2.624c1.463,0,2.653,1.177,2.653,2.624V444.215L256.653,444.215z"/>
    </g>
</g>
</svg>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Wanted to upload it, but SO don't let me upload SVG image

Comment: @FrontDev – Just add the markup, then.  Don't need to upload anything.

Comment: Ah ok, please see my update above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing any attribute where it says `sketch:type="..."` throughout the svg code.

Comment: Works, Thanks!! anyway can you please tell how can I remove that options before saving it in Illustrator?

Comment: I suspect those attributes weren't put there by Illustrator.  Did you import the file originally from Sketch perhaps?

Comment: Honestly said I haven't much experience in that :( just had SVG icons which combine in illustrator and saved as SVG